# how to download ubuntu onto windows xp computer

Tags: uninstall

I have downloaded ubuntu onto my computer but the computer wants to use windows media player to read the file which it cannot so what do I need to do ?

Comment: You are looking to install ubuntu, right? This should help: [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)